# Quickcam driver for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, webcam

Is there a way to get a Quickcam Pro 4000/5000 to work on Windows 7? The website shows that there are only drivers available for XP and Vista. Maybe an open source webcam driver project?

Comment: Try the vista driver. It should be similar enough to work. Somewhere in M$'s economic propaganda documents concerning windows 7 it said that it will be compatible with Vi$ta's drivers for almost all hardware. I doubt that you will be able to find open-source driver for windows, but I could be wrong.